# How to fetch records from two different tables in laravel5.2

Tags: mysql, orm, laravel-5

I have two tables 'approval' and 'renewal', both having a common column 'applicant_id'.

When new application comes-in, it stores a data-record in table 'approval' alongwith the 'applicant_id' for whom the record has been added.

Now, when there is a renew applied for that same applicant, the row gets created in the table 'renewal' referencing the 'applicant_id'

Note: There can be a single record in the table 'approval' for a 'applicant_id' but there can be more than one record for the same 'applicant_id' in the table 'renewal'.

Now, my requirement is: 
I need to fetch the records from both the table for all the applicants.

Conditions: If there is a data for the 'applicant_id' in both the table and 'renewal' table has multiple row for the same 'applicant_id', then I need to get the records from 'renewal' table only that too the latest one.
If there is no data in 'renewal' table but exists in 'approval' table for the 'applicant_id', then the fetch record should get the data present in 'approval' table.
Basically, if there is record for the applicant in 'renewal' table, get the latest one from there, if there is record present only in 'approval' table, then get that one but the preference should be to get from 'renewal' if exists.

I am trying to do this in laravel 5.2. So, is there anyone who can help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few try, I got one way to do it using raw:

```
SELECT applicant_id, applicant_name, applicant_email, applicant_phone, renewed, updated_at
FROM  (
SELECT renewal_informations.applicant_id, renewal_informations.applicant_name, renewal_informations.applicant_email, renewal_informations.applicant_phone, renewal_informations.renewed, renewal_informations.updated_at 
FROM renewal_informations
UNION ALL
SELECT approval_informations.applicant_id, approval_informations.applicant_name, approval_informations.applicant_email, approval_informations.applicant_phone, approval_informations.renewed, approval_informations.updated_at 
FROM approval_informations
) result
GROUP BY applicant_id
ORDER BY applicant_id ASC, updated_at DESC;
```

Comment: Anyone if have a better approach, then please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eloquent, you'll have 2 models:

### Renewal.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Eloquent\Model;

class Renewal extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'renewal';

    public static function findMostRecentByApplicantId($applicantId)
    {
        $applicant = self::where('applicant_id', '=', $applicantId)
                         ->orderBy('date_created', 'desc')
                         ->first();

        return $applicant;
    }
}
```

### Approval.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Eloquent\Model;

class Approval extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'approval';

    public static function findByApplicantId($applicantId)
    {
        $applicant = self::where('applicant_id', '=', $applicantId)
                         ->first();

        return $applicant;
    }
}
```

Then, in the code where you want to get the approval/renewal record, use the following code:

```
if (! $record = Renewal::findMostRecentByApplicantId($applicantId)) {
    $record = Approval::findByApplicantId($applicantId);
}

//$record will now either contain a valid record (approval or renewal) 
//or will be NULL if no record exists for the specified $applicantId
```

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful way to answer but my requirement is like:
I need to get records for all the applicants and not based on particular applicant.
I am trying to fetch all the records so that I can list them in a datatable for the managers who will have a look to the latest activity applied/done on all the applications present.

Answer (score 0):

For every single Approval id, there can b multiple records for renewal table suggests you have One to Many relation. which you can define in the your Model like

Approval.php (App\Models\Approval)

```
public function renewal()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Renewal', 'applicant_id')
}
```

Having defined this relation. you can get the records from the table using applicant_id.

```
$renewal_request_records = Approval::find($applicant_id)->renewal();
```

This will get all records from renewal table against that applicant_id.

**Finding the latest**

```
$latest = Renewal::orderBy('desc', 'renewal_id')->first();
```

Further Readings [Eloquent Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: It is not obvious that there will be a record in the table 'renewal'. Anyway, thanks for your effort!